# why is Outlook 2007 continuously losing Connection to Exchange Server

Tags: exchange, outlook

what could be the reason for Outlook 2007 continously losing and reestablishing the connection to exchange?

I tried disabling all anti-viruses and firewalls but it did not help.

I should mention that even though this seems to happen to all users, some users cannot even send emails because it happens every few seconds while others can work relatively undisturbed (it happens a few times per hour).

Comment: IS this on an ethernet network, or wireless?

Answer (score 2):

This is a common issue with Outlook 2007 running in Cached mode (I used get this all the time).  Disable Cached Exchange Mode and you'll see the symptom disappear.  However, your junk mail and a few other features will behave slightly different, but will still continue to function (in a different capacity).

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem with RPC/Http connections. I ended up doing a repair on my mailbox while in RPC mode. Outlook could not determine my settings from the exchange server, so I accepted all the current settings, but once completed magically everything worked. I was no longer forced to authorize every time I open up Outlook. I suspect that outlook is caching old credentials and failing once your passwords change.